# TypeScript error - Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

In my code I am getting following TypeScript error. I have tried almost all the solutions but none of them worked for me. I cannot set  `strictNullChecks: false` in `tsconfig.json` file. I am looking for different solution

Error 1-
`Argument of type 'BuildMember | undefined' is not assignable of type 'BuildMember'` at `1st Error`

Error 2- `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BuildMember'.` at `2nd and 3rd Error`

Object is possible 'undefined' at 2nd and 3rd Error

Here is `Interface`

```
export interface BuildMember {
  tool?: BuildMember[];
  hastool?: boolean;
  };
}
```

WindowComponent.ts

```
export class WindowComponent {
  @Output() selectEvent = new EventEmitter<BuildMember>();
    focus?: BuildMember;
  constructor() { // some code}

  checkData(possible: string, serviceData: string) {
    if (serviceData == "X") {
      this.focus = this.yankService.run.tool.filter(
        (data: BuildMember) => data.treepossible == possible[0])[0];
    } 

    this.displaytool(this.focus).then(async () => {   ---------->>>>>  1st Error
      var temp: String[] = []; 
      if (possible.length > 1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < possibles.length - 1; i++) {
          temp.push(possibles[i]);
          match = temp.join(".");
          if (this.focus !== undefined) {
            this.focus = this.focus.tool.filter(
              (data: BuildMember) => data.treepossible == match)[0];  ------->>>  2nd Error
            await this.displaytoolNoToggle(this.focus);
          }
        }
        if (this.focus) {
          this.focus = this.focus.tool.filter(
            (data: BuildMember) => data.treepossible == possible)[0];  ------>>>  3rd Error
          this.yankService.select(this.focus);
        }
      }
    });
  }  
}
```

Comment: Does the code here constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?  If not, then please consider providing such an example so that others can more easily demonstrate your issue for themselves and suggest answers that they themselves have tested.  Good luck!

Comment: Maybe that will help someone else find your issue, but note that a [mcve] is supposed to be *minimal*: it should feature the least amount of code required to demonstrate the problem... and should not have anything unrelated in there (e.g., `HostResourceResolver: could not resolve ./treeView.component.html in context of /~/src/app/app.component.ts`).

Comment: Okay, but this is a big project with many dependencies. Do you think if I add some more code that will help to solve the issue?

Comment: Please do consult the guidelines about [ask] and specifically read about what constitutes a [mcve].